# What is the average ground clearance of a Lamborghini?

Tags: lamborghini

What is the average ground clearance for a Lamborghini? Let's consider a few models for the last years with highest and smallest values.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about vehicle repair.

Comment: @Larry, what is the appropriate site in the network to ask this question ? thanks

Comment: There's not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aventador - 4.1"
Gallardo - 5.0", but variable
Countach - 5.0"